# MVC EditorFor date doesn't update the sub property in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing the model to the View and then I want to change user.BannEndDate in the view and send it back to the controller.
No matter what I will do with user.BannEndDate ActionLink always pass the value which was set by arrived model. Can anyone help me with that ?

[Model]

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? BannEndDate { get; set; }
```

[View]

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Bann", "BannUser", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, bann = true, bannEndDate = user.BannEndDate} , null)
    @Html.EditorFor(u => user.BannEndDate)
}
```

[Controller]

```
public ActionResult BannUser(string userId, bool bann, DateTime? bannEndDate){}
```

Comment: That is expected behavior because the `ActionLink` is rendered while `user.BannEndDate` is the previous value. That's the nature of a server-side framework like ASP.NET MVC. If you want to send it back to the server, put it in a form and submit it. If you want the `ActionLink` to update on the client-side, you'll need to use client-side code. In other words, JavaScript. There are a number of questions about how to do that here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, I thought editorfor will update client-side value too. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Rather than using `ActionLink()` just use a form with `FormMethod.Get` which will post back the value of the textbox to your GET method (no javascript required)

Comment: Yes, but then I have to create a form for each textbox, I thought I can pass Model by Razor without form. It's also good idea but i think javascript is lighter ?

Comment: To be clear my target is to click the link and update DB by datepicker value, so I think forms are for collection of data not for updating one record, maybe I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: It that case it should definitely be a form that submits to a POST method - you should never be changing data in a GET method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike McCaughan already stated, the values for `@Html.ActionLink` are static, since they're written when you call the page.

What you could do, is give your `ActionLink` and `EditorFor` a specific ID.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Bann", "BannUser", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, bann = true, bannEndDate = user.EndDate }, new { @id = "TargetLink_" + user.Id })
@Html.EditorFor(m => user.BannEndDate, null, "BannEndDate_" + user.Id)
```

After that you can listen to changes on those controls via jQuery and change your ActionLink (`userId = 3` will result in `BannEndDate_3` and `TargetLink_3`):

```
$('input[id*="BannEndDate_"]').change((e) => {
    var userId = e.target.id.substr(e.target.id.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var link = $("#TargetLink_" + userId).attr('href');
    $("#TargetLink_" + userId).attr('href', link.replace(/(bannEndDate=.*$)/g, 'bannEndDate=' + encodeURIComponent($("#" + e.target.id).val())));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, i thought Razor will immediatly update Model in all site scope and every method will get changed referenced object value but it was wrong way.

Comment: If you really want to do that, simply use  POST (`[HttpPost]`) Methods and pass a `Model` to the Controller.